# Start Vim window at a certain size?

Tags: vimrc, gvim, vim9

Is there anything I can put in my `_vimrc` for gVim to make the window open a certain width/height?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use:

```
if has('gui_running')
  set columns=80
  set lines=20
endif
```

Comment: If doing so for gvim, use the gvimrc. Otherwise this affects non-gvim too

Comment: ... or wrap in a `if has('gui_running')` block.